# Return all data where a value does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if a job does not have an 'LI' CompCode.

```
SELECT 
    bSLHD.Job, SLCT.SL, APVM.Vendor, APVM.Name, SLCT.CompCode, SLCT.ExpDate 
FROM 
    bSLHD
INNER JOIN 
    SLCT ON bSLHD.SL = SLCT.SL
INNER JOIN 
    APVM ON bSLHD.Vendor = APVM.Vendor
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: I added this info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT bSLHD.Job
FROM bSLHD INNER JOIN
     SLCT
     ON bSLHD.SL = SLCT.SL INNER JOIN
     APVM
     ON bSLHD.Vendor = APVM.Vendor
GROUP BY bSLHD.Job
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN SLCT.CompCode = 'LI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: I want to know if a job does not have an 'LI' CompCode.

Comment: @dev_help . . . That is exactly what this code should be doing.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

At the moment you are joining the tables to one recordset. Next you should add conditions which rows of that you want to see. On your case, you DO NOT want rows where CompCode is 'LI'.

Try to add one of those to the end of your SQL statement.

1: CompCode "is not equal to" 'LI'

```
WHERE SLCT.CompCode != 'LI'
```

2: CompCode is "smaller than (or) greather than" 'LI'

```
WHERE SLCT.CompCode <> 'LI'
```

3: CompCode "is not similar to" 'LI'

```
WHERE SLCT.CompCode not like 'LI'
```

Comment: I need a list of only jobs that do not have a record that contains 'LI'.

Comment: note the " !" sign before "=" sign. " != " means "not equal". Also you coult try "SLCT.CompCode <> 'LI'

Comment: I want to know if a job does not have an 'LI' CompCode.